# Volume by 3 Planes

Tags: integration

I'm new to Integration Problem. For now i'm pretty messed up with this Volume Problem. Can anyone please revise it!

Calculate the Volume of interception of three planes which is given by equation $z^2=2x$,  $x=1$  $y^2=4x$

So far i made this:

Limits of $x,y,z$. $0\le x \le 1$, $-2x\le y \le 2x$, $-\sqrt{y} \le z \le \sqrt{y}$

$$S = \int_0 ^1\int_{-2x}^{2x}\int_{-\sqrt y}^{\sqrt y}1dzdydx$$ so as result i have $4\over3$.

I don't know whether i did something right or wrong.

Any help greatly appreciated

thanks

Comment: The equations $\;z^2=2x\;,\;\;y^2=4x\;$ are *not* planes' . Did you mean something else?

Comment: No. that is exactly the Problem written on the book.

Comment: @Joanpemo Perhaps an unfortunate translation into English. “Surfaces” would make more sense.

Comment: @amd Thank you. Yes, most probably a mistranslation.

Comment: Yeah it could be. i found this Problem on german Analysis book.